# How to use regex_iterator with const char/wchar_t*?

Tags: c++, regex, windows

How to use the `regex_iterator` on data types of `const char*/wchar_t*`?

From docs:

> using cregex_iterator = regex_iterator<const char*>;
>
> using wcregex_iterator = regex_iterator<const wchar_t*>;
>
> using sregex_iterator = regex_iteratorstring::const_iterator;
>
> using wsregex_iterator = regex_iteratorwstring::const_iterator;

Reproducible example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

template <typename T>
auto RegexMatchAll(const T* str, const T* regex)
{
    using iter = std::regex_iterator<T>;
    std::basic_regex<T> re(regex);
    auto words_begin = iter(str, (str + std::wcslen(str)), re); // <--- how to iterate according to the data in this case?
    auto words_end = iter();

    std::vector<std::match_results<iter>> result;

    for (iter i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
         std::match_results<iter> m = *i;
         result.emplace_back(m);
    }  

    return result; 
}

int main() {
     auto matches = RegexMatchAll(L"10,20,30", LR"((\d+))"); 
}
```

Comment: Last thing you are missing from the question is what you expect and what actually happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors.  Assuming you pass a `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`, `T` will be `char` or `wchar_t`, so:

- `std::regex_iterator` expects an iterator type, which neither `char` nor `wchar_t` are.  You want to pass it `const T*` instead.
- `*i` will yeild a `std::match_results<const T*>` as well, so that's the type you should store in your `result` vector.
- `std::wcslen` is only good for `T = wchar_t`, you need to use `std::strlen` when `T = char`.  I would create an overloaded wrapper function that calls the appropriate standard library function.

Putting that all together, something like this should work:

```
std::size_t str_len(const char* s) { return std::strlen(s); }
std::size_t str_len(const wchar_t* s) { return std::wcslen(s); }

template <typename T>
auto RegexMatchAll(const T* str, const T* regex)
{
    using iter = std::regex_iterator<const T*>;
    std::basic_regex<T> re(regex);
    auto words_begin = iter(str, str + str_len(str), re);
    auto words_end = iter();

    return std::vector<std::match_results<const T*>>(words_begin, words_end);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51fbff66c98f735f)

---

Note: I also simplified the `std::vector` construction to use its iterator pair constructor.

Comment: `Assuming you pass a const char* or const wchar_t*, T will be char or wchar_t` why?

Comment: @Nathan Because the function accepts `const T*`s, if `T` was `const char*` that would make `const const char* *`, which is clearly not what the function accepts.

Comment: should i avoid doing this? -> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f33ee0c24623c919 this way woudnt need to declare the overloaded wrapper

Comment: @Nathan You could.  You would need to declare `words_begin` outside the `if` and assign to it within.  I think the overloaded function is a bit cleaner and less repetitive though.

Comment: I didn't understand what you did in the 'simplified' vector, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Nathan `std::vector` (like all of the other standard containers) has a constructor that accepts a pair of iterators designating a range of elements to copy into the new vector.  Constructor (5) on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: I see ty, why does each index of the vector contains a duplicate of the matched number?

Comment: @Nathan It doesn't; it contains a `std::match_results`.  `std::vector`'s iterator range constructor has the exact same effect as your `for` loop: it copies each element in the range into the vector.  It just does it for you instead of needing to write out the loop.

Comment: [0] [1] stores same match on each index of the vector https://i.imgur.com/49OpBT2.png

Comment: @Nathan Ah, I see what you mean.  That comes down to how your regex is defined.  Group 0 will always be the entire match.  Since you have a capturing group in your regex that becomes group 1.  Since nothing is matched outside that capturing group both groups are the same.  If you pattern was something like `\d(\d+)` then group 0 would be `"419"` and group 1 would be `"19"` in the first element of the vector in your screenshot, for example.

Comment: Im reading the link you sent, so basically what you did in the vector was something like: `std::vector<int>first = { 1,2,3 }; std::vector<int>second(first);`

Comment: @Nathan More like `std::vector<int> first = {1, 2, 3}; std::vector<int> second(first.begin(), first.end());`.  Same result though.

Comment: But why `std::match_results<const T*>` filled all `matches` in the vector if you didn't iterate it? its already storing all matches? I'm asking cause in the code i post i was iterating and pushing each match

Comment: @Nathan Because that's what that constructor does.  Just like `std::vector<int> second(first.begin(), first.end())` copies all of the elements in the range `[first.begin(), first.end())`, `std::vector<std::match_results<const T*>>(words_begin, words_end)` copies all of the elements in the range `[words_begin, words_end)`.  `*first.begin()` is an `int`, so that's what `second` copies.  `*words_begin` is a `std::match_results<const T*>`, so that's what the vector returned by `RegexMatchAll` copies.